# What is the point of copying an object that is immutable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objc I see this code:

```
- (void)setSubtitle:(NSAttributedString *)subtitle
{
    self.subtitleLabel.attributedText = [subtitle copy];
}
```

It is basically copying a string, which is immutable.
Is there any reason? Is this an advantage or a wasting of time?
I cannot ask the author because, well, he is not here anymore.
I don't see the point of doing that.

Comment: Note that copying an immutable object doesn't actually copy anything;  it returns the same instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of `copy` is because someone can actually pass a mutable attributed string to your `setSubtitle:` method. The use of `copy` ensures you have an immutable copy of the attribute string just in case the original mutable version is modified.

But in this case it is pointless because the `attributedText` property of `UILabel` is declared as `copy` so you actually have a redundant call to `copy` in your code.

Comment: To clarify: `NSMutableAttributedString` is declared as a subclass of `NSAttributedString`. So anyplace you take an `NSAttributedString`, you could actually get the subclass. If someone then mutates the string, your value will change underneath you. So the convention is to copy incoming immutable objects so you don't have to worry about randomly changing values.